# getting rid of nested li text-decorations when parent has text-decorations

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqvcr/53/

This is so damn basic and I have no idea how to make it work.

How do I keep the .selected class underlined while the drop down list anchors have no underline?

The HTML:

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
        <a href="work.html">Work</a>
        <ul id="second" class="vis">
            <li>
                <a href="graphicdesign.html">Graphic Design</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="illustrations.html">Illustrations</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- etcetera -->
```

​The CSS:

```css
ul#nav {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline;
}
ul#nav li {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
ul#nav li.first {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-left: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
ul#second {
    position: absolute;
    right: -57px;
    display: none;
}
.selected {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.selected:hover ul#second {
    display: block;
}
.selected:hover ul#second li a {
    display: block;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle, only `"Work"` in underlined, that's what you want, right?

Comment: yeah i just want work to be underlined

Comment: It works like it should in your fiddle. What happens when you click an `"about"` link? Can I see your project online somewhere, so I can click the links?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a browser specific problem. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: FYI, your markup is not valid - you're not closing the topmost `ul`.

Comment: Eliran Malka: Take a look at the fiddle, it is valid. Above is just a small part of his actual code.

Comment: i see. updating your post to show this, please accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're more specific with the selector that underlines the link you want, it becomes easier to select other items within that you don't want underlined. I changed

```
.selected {text-decoration:underline;}
```

to:

```
.selected a {text-decoration:underline;}
```

Also, added `text-decoration: none;` like so:

```
.selected:hover ul#second li a {display:block; text-decoration: none;}
```

See it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/Lqvcr/54/)

Comment: What browser are you using? Just checked on Windows 7 in Firefox and Chrome, looked fine in both. The layout is (always was) broken in IE9 but the effect is as required.

Comment: @cchana The first change is made redundent by the second change (you do not need to add the `a` in the selector). If you did want to add the `a` then use `.selected > a {text-decoration:underline;}' Then you wouldn't have to bother with the second change.

Answer (score 3):

Simply change this line :

```
.selected a{text-decoration:underline;}
```

for this one :

```
.selected > a{text-decoration:underline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to declare a rule for the `.selected` selector, and override it for lower level elements.

as the desired style for `.selected` (`text-decoration: underlined;`) is the user agent default, i omitted some `text-decoration` declarations. all that's left to be done is add the rule for lower level elements, defined with high specificity:

```css
.selected:hover ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

​
here's the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqvcr/57/), for demonstration.

Comment: @Matthew Harwood: I'm on Windows 7, using Chrome, and all these fiddles work for me. I would consider improving CSS code for whatever browser you are using